# Sonarqube Delphi plugin

Tags: delphi, plugins, sonarqube

I have scoured the web looking for the Sonar Delphi plugin 0.2 (sonar-delphi-plugin-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar). Since the shutdown of codehaus, it seems this plugin is not available anywhere else?

http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-delphi-plugin/0.2-SNAPSHOT/

There is several references to this URL, but I cannot find this plugin anywhere else.

Does someone please know where I can download it, or possibly has it available to share?

Comment: Does [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsonardelphiplugin01sourcesjar.htm) help? Looks like 0.1 to me, though, not 0.2.

Comment: I do have the sonar-delphi-plugin-0.2-SNAPSHOT. The download sites I know of are shut down. How can I send it to you?

Comment: Hi @TimHauschildt, you can email it to me at mariusbloemhof@gmail.com, or alternatively contact me there and we can  make arrangements. Much appreciated!

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I did manage to come across that one, it is 0.1 though. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin was abandoned and picked up by Fabricio Colombo and relocated to github
https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi

Look at 'Releases' to get the latest plugin .jar

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the 0.2 snapshot...  it appears that you can use the "Wayback Machine" internet archive to grab it at:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140324100408/http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-delphi-plugin/0.2-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 0):

I have just published an updated version our SonarQube Delphi plugin which supports Sonar 7.9 LTS and also the latest 8.2 version, see https://github.com/mendrix/SonarDelphi.

If you combine this with the DelphiCodeCoverage tool (see https://sourceforge.net/projects/delphicodecoverage/) and DUnitX (including the additional file in our SonarQube repository) you have a fully functioning SonarQube plugin for Delphi.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192).

Answer (score -1):

GitHub has these three projects of Sonar from Codehaus:

https://github.com/codehaus?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=sonar

The project *[sonar-plugins](https://github.com/codehaus/sonar-plugins)* is empty but references on https://github.com/sonarcommunity.
There are plenty of plugins. See if you can find it there.

Comment: The plugin he asks for is not available there.

Comment: @René Hoffmann, it is not there, but i did manage to find what seems to be a usefull custom branch of 0.1, with source (https://github.com/c-mckenna/sonar-delphi), which could be usefull - thanks for your help