# How to Configure SonarQube for delphi?

Tags: delphi, plugins, configuration, sonarqube

I want to configure SonarQube so it can analyze Delphi project too, and when I search online I saw there used to be a delphi plugin for SonarQube. But when I look at the plugins with the latest build it doesn't show the delphi plugin.

Is the plugin still available in an other way?

Or is it possible to configure SonarQube for delphi without the plugin?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31849448/4236400 ?

Comment: @RenéHoffmann Yes, at the community plugins page there is also no plugin for delphi

Comment: There is a link in a comment: https://github.com/c-mckenna/sonar-delphi

Comment: @mjn that seems to be source code and not the plugin itself

Comment: You can build the plugin from source: * install JDK * install Maven * run `mvn` in the source root directory * find the plugin in target subdir

Comment: There are code analysis tools for delphi, like fixinsight or pascal analyzer or castilia or codehealer. Can you use one of these for your purpose?

Comment: @Johan yes maybe. I'll look into it. Are all of those compatible with delphi and open source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of G. Ann response was actually discontinued puglin for Sonar, but searching the internet, and recently (3 days) the developer [Fabricio Columbus](https://github.com/fabriciocolombo) made it happen!

We tested and is running the current version of Sonar:

Compatible with SonarQube 4.5.x and SonarQube 5.1.2
https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi

Release: https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi/releases
JAR: https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi/releases/download/0.3.3-SNAPSHOT/sonar-delphi-plugin-0.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

PS: Translated from Portuguese to English by Google Translate.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what to do with that. It's source code only. Not the plugin itself. Do you have a link for the .jar file of the plugin itself?

Comment: Later I upload and place the Link

Comment: And what parameters do you need to use? Is sonar.language=delphi? Or sonar.language=.pas?

Comment: I believe that "delph", download the repository that has a set every instance, will help you better. https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi/tree/master/samples

Comment: JAM Software created a fork of the SonarDelphi plugin. We fixed various grammar issues and a few others: https://github.com/JAM-Software/SonarDelphi

Answer (score 2):

To analyze the files of language X, you need a plugin for language X that recognize's X's structure, syntax &etc. Without that you can't derive metrics (LOC, complexity, &etc.) or recognize bad code (i.e. raise issues for antipatterns.) So to answer your second question first, you won't be able to analyze Delphi code without some kind of Delphi plugin.

The Delphi plugin was deprecated quite a while ago because it seemed to suffer from a lack of interest all around & didn't evolve to maintain compatibility with the platform as it evolved.

If you look, you can find downloads of the old plugin, but to use it, you'd have to retrogress to a quite old version of the platform, & I don't recommend that. I'm not sure how far back you'd have to go - you could crack open the jar and get that from the pom - but it looks like the last mailing list activity on this plugin was Feb. 2012. So again, I don't recommend going this route.

Comment: Ok, that's to bad. Do you know which version would be compatible with the delphi plugin?

Comment: @David I already found the plugin itself, but it's not compatible with the latest version of SonarQube

Answer (score 1):

**2023 answer:**

IntegraDev has released a new SonarDelphi plugin that works on current versions of SonarQube, and is also a fair bit more powerful/advanced than the previous implementations.

It's available in the SonarQube Marketplace.

See: https://github.com/integrated-application-development/sonar-delphi